# How to suppress the output message in vertica

Tags: message, vertica

I am running a series of SQL statement in vertica which is saved in abc.sql file and transferring the output to a text file.

I wanted to suppress the warning message and stop it from going to text file

```
abc.sql 

UPDATE  public.aks SET name='Akshay';

SELECT 2;

SELECT 3;

SELECT 4;
```

output.txt

```
OUTPUT
100
(1 row)
?column?
2
(1 row)
?column?
3
(1 row)
?column?
4
(1 row)
```

Comment: Are you running the script with `vsql`?  Can you share your command?

Comment: Yes i am running this command    /opt/vertica/bin/vsql footer=off  -h 10.61.8.901 -p 5283 -U XYX -w XYX -d databasename --set AUTOCOMMIT='ON' -F $'\t' -A -f "/home/biops/scripts/temp_scripts/abc.sql">>aksay.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to switch output on and off within the script.

Preparing the table:

```
CREATE TABLE public.aks AS
WITH 
-- need a series of integers ..
i AS (
  SELECT MICROSECOND(ts) AS i , 'slartibartfast' AS name FROM (
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(microsecond,  1,'2000-01-01'::TIMESTAMP) AS tm UNION ALL
    SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(microsecond,100,'2000-01-01'::TIMESTAMP) AS tm
  )x
  TIMESERIES ts AS '1 microsecond' OVER(ORDER BY tm)
)
SELECT * FROM i;
```

Once that is done - the script looks like this:

```
-- send all output to nirvana
\o /dev/null
UPDATE  public.aks SET name='Akshay';
-- send output back to screen
\o
SELECT 2;
SELECT 3;
SELECT 4;
```

And the output:

```
2
3
4
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 1):

This video I made a while back goes over several format options including what you are looking for: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d3f3fvMGDnU

If you add the `-t` option, it will not show you how many rows are returned or the column headers. Looks like you are already using the `-A` option, so adding the `-t` option should be all you need to create properly delimited file contents.

Comment: Hi, Saunders Your approach worked but there is a problem, Even the number of updated rows are still showing now after changing the current output is :

100
2
3
4

I want to remove 100 also since it is reflecting the number of rows updated